How do I run my program after compilation (C/C++)
I am new to both emacs and CMake so getting the two to even compile a program in the first place was a big hurdle. But I managed to do it, and now I am wondering how I would go about making it so that the program runs after it has been compiled (like in visual studio).
Right now I have to open up a seperate console and run the executable in the build folder manually.
I use the CMake IDE in the CMake layer (https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+tools/cmake/README.html)
and to compile I use [SPC m p c]

The IDE might have such capabilities (I wouldn't know), but you can always run a shell command. If your executable is called a.out, you can say M-x shell-command RET ./a.out arg1 arg2 ...., just as if you were running it from a terminal (or the spacemacs equivalent - which I wouldn't know either).
